# Why can I use a column from a different table in a subquery?

Tags: sql, oracle

In this example, I feel like I shouldn't be able to make this mistake:

```
create table A (A_ID int);
create table B (B_ID int, OTHER_ID int);

insert into A values (123);
insert into B values (456, 123);

select * from A where A_ID in (select A_ID from B);
```

The correct query would be this:

```
select * from A where A_ID in (select OTHER_ID from B);
```

Since A_ID does not exist in table B, why doesn't the query throw an error, or at least fail?

Edit: Thanks for the replies! However, to be clear, my question isn't "what's the right way to do this?", I was just curious why this would work.

Comment: I get an invalid identifier error when I run the subquery, as expected.  There is something else going on then.

Comment: Because how else would correlated subqueries be possible?

Comment: @OldProgrammer strange; it works for me. I wouldn't expect it to error, since it's a correlated subquery and is perfectly valid syntax!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your query, this is how its functioning. A_ID is working like a constant.

```
select * from dual
 where 123 in (select 123 from dual);
```

`123` doesn't exists in dual, but since a row exists in dual, you can select any value you like.

```
select * from dual;
```

Output -

```
Dummy
X
```

As per OP's query -

```
select * from A where A_ID in (select A_ID from B);
```

If the above query was

```
select * from A where A_ID in (select A_ID from B where 1=2);
```

It wouldn't return any records.

Scope of column names comes into picture, when there are same column names, which require qualification via Table Alias

Comment: @underscore_d isn't that contradictory of sorts ? Something which is easier to understand might be a better explanation, right ? `just asking`

Comment: I think you meant to comment on the question up above

Comment: @anonymouse nope, [at]undercore_d deleted his comment to which I replied.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not how it really works. This analogy is erroneous. It all comes down to the scope and name resolution.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov I believe name resolution will only come into picture, when the column names are same in more than 1 table/block/scope.

Answer (score 5):

You should always include qualified table names when your write queries with more than one column.  Your first query is interpreted as:

```
select a.*
from A a
where a.A_ID in (select a.A_ID from B b);
```

This is called a correlated subquery.  They are allowed everywhere, except in the `FROM` clause.

You should be writing the query as:

```
select a.*
from A a
where a.A_ID in (select b.OTHER_ID from B b);
```

This prevents any errors.  If you had qualified the column names originally, then your query would have (presumably) generated an error:

```
select a.*
from A a
where a.A_ID in (select b.A_ID from B b);
```

Comment: That's what we ended up doing. I was just unclear as to why it was possible to get away with not specifying in cases like the one I posted

Comment: "should always qualify* is a matter of opinion. As long as the code clear and readable, use qualification only as necessary. Same goes for aliases, which are also completely unnecessary here: `... from A .... (select A.A_ID ...)` is fine.

Answer (score 3):

The subqueries that you are talking about are called *correlated subqueries*: these are queries that run under the context of the main query, and hence these provide access to any field that is part of the main query.

Think that it would not make lots of sense not allowing this kind of usage of the fields of the main query as otherwise the SQL would lose lots of power.

You can find further information in the [Oracle Help Center](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries007.htm#SQLRF52357).

Answer (score 3):

It works because of *scope*.

All columns of the outer query are in the scope (visible to) subqueries.

You don't need to qualify columns, for example `A.A_ID` in:

```
select * from A where A_ID in (select A.A_ID from B)
```

if there's no ambiguity in the narrowest scope in which the column is found. For example, if `B` had a column `A_ID` you wouldn't need to qualify it, but if there were multiple columns in outer queries called , you would need to qualify it to disambiguate the reference.